# Does cold damage count as slow?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I'm playing as a Demon Hunter and recently I was looking at the passive skills when I saw [***Cull the Weak***](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/cull-the-weak) skill that increases damage against slow enemies by 15%.

The question is: does this skill only work with the effects of the other skills([*Caltrops*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/caltrops), [*Rapid Fire with Web Shot rune*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/rapid-fire), [*Entangling Shot*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/entangling-shot), etc)?

Or does cold damage on the weapon also count as slow effect for this skill?

If so, then a 2-hand Bow with some cold damage, [*Archery*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/archery), [*Cull the Weak*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/cull-the-weak) and [*Steady Aim*](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/steady-aim) would give a nice +50% damage bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this discussion](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?833912-Cull-the-Weak-Cold-damage-interaction) it seems that cold damage does count as a slow, and the bonus damage will even apply to your initial hit.