# Does blizzard actually slow enemies down and by how much?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Some runes like grasping chill slow enemies down. What about the others?

My main use of [blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/blizzard) is not really to damage enemy but to slow them down for poison hydra.

The tooltips doesn't say it snares at all. It says it does cold damage it doesn't say it slows enemies. If it does by how much?

To make it clear. My extensive experience shows that yes blizzard slow. I want to make sure of it. Also I want to know by how much. [Does Cold Damage Slow Enemy Movement Speed Only?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76441/does-cold-damage-slow-enemy-movement-speed-only) is related and there is no answer for that either.

Comment: The 2nd line is subjective; and also incorrect - all the mobs I've killed while kiting with blizzard would disagree ;). Also, blizzard does cold damage which always slows.

Comment: The cold damage probably slows them the same amount all cold damage does.  See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74682/does-cold-damage-count-as-slow)

Comment: Probably... You don't know for sure yourself yet downvotes. I want to make suee

Comment: and damage from poison hydra is far more than blizzard.

Comment: This link is more informative http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4211005562

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted.  It's a legitimate question and as far as I've seen there's been no definitive answer.  I'd like to know how much cold damage slows as well, I've seen both 20% and 30% in the discussions posted.

Comment: @JesseM - It's been edited and the downvotes are from the first version, which didn't really seem to have a question in it.

Comment: I think the question would probably be better off if it was changed to just "How much does cold damage slow enemies?", since it is clear to anyone that has used the spell that it does slow them.

Comment: @Jason Fair enough.

Comment: Fair enough. I think the effectively 2 questions title is fine for now. Even though it's obvious that blizzard snare, it's not that obvious because it's not on the tooltips.

Comment: Actually because it's not on the tooltips, whether blizzard snares at all is not obvious.

Comment: Should I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1):

All blizzards slow enemies by 30%.  Grasping Chill has an additional slowing effect after the blizzard is over, by leaving ice on the ground.

Source: My own testing, since none of the books or tooltips suggest Blizzard slows enemies.  You will always see "snared" come up on monsters as they are hit by the blizzard though.